# Laravel-5 Queueing mail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to queue mail using Laravel-5.  The code I am using is below.  I was expecting the mail to get stored in the database in the 'jobs' table but it just gets sent instantly.

```
Mail::queue('emails.orderthankyou', ['first_name' => 'My Name'], function ($m) {
    $m->to('me@myemail.com')->subject('Test');
});
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Comment: are you running `php artisan queue:listen` in background. If you are Email may be queued and jobs processed before you can browse table.

Comment: Did you set up the queue properly? It defaults to the `sync` driver, which fires immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `Mail::later` instead.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail

```
Mail::later(5, 'emails.orderthankyou', ['first_name' => 'My Name'], function ($m) {
    $m->to('me@myemail.com')->subject('Test');
});
```

Comment: 5 is in seconds, so that may seem instant.. Also you probably misinterpret the queue. The queue is for handling tasks one after each other. You can't schedule tasks for a certain date/time.

Comment: So whats the difference between this and storing queued jobs in the database?

Answer (score 2):

You might be using `sync` driver ( in config/queue.php ). `sync` stands for synchronous. Therefore, all jobs are executed instantly.

Comment: I suspect this is the answer. `sync` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

**Delayed Message Queueing**

> If you wish to delay the delivery of a queued e-mail message, you may
>   use the later method. To get started, simply pass the number of
>   **seconds** by which you wish to delay the sending of the message as the
>   first argument to the method:

```
Mail::later(5, 'emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
//here 5 is the number of seconds
});
```